# WebService To communicate with mongoDB

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, mongodb

I need a web-service to connect to mongoDB in iOS app. Is there anything already available on the web? Kindly help.

Comment: connecting to remote database from iOS application is the worst thing that I can imagine...

Comment: Why? Can you elaborate please.

Comment: because everyone can debug/disassembly/sniff/trace your application, and find Database credentials,  so after that connect to your server, read/edit your database.